Cannot repair a disk with corrupted GPT using gdisk
I have a disk that was forcefully closed when it was working in a disk operation (when downloading files to it). Now, the GPT is corrupted and I cannot mount it correctly. I am trying to mount it using the automount feature of Disks program, and sometimes I see some files, after a long period (many folders appear as lost or missing when using mc).
Firstly. I tried to repair it using fsck, then e2fsck. But later I realized that the GPT is corrupted. The latter program said that a superblock is corrupted. Not even backing up with one of the suggested superblocks resolved the problem.
I tried to repair it using gdisk, but I cannot even enter the menu mode:
# gdisk /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.10

Problem reading disk in BasicMBRData::ReadMBRData()!
Warning! Read error 22; strange behavior now likely!
Warning! Read error 22; strange behavior now likely!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by
typing 'q' if you don't want to convert your MBR partitions
to GPT format!
***************************************************************

Disk is too small to hold GPT data (0 sectors)! Aborting!

Disks program reports 0 size for the whole disk, a 1 TB ST1000LM035-1RK172 (LCM2). However, also reports the disk is OK. In fact, it was OK before the brute force closing of the laptop.
The partitions of this disk are the following, according to fdisk (sometimes, I can access the disk, then it reports I/O error):
$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for simonapetra: 
The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LM035-1RK1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 68FC7421-1B80-4C35-B2B7-BEE10E092543

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1          34      32767     32734    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2       32768  174112767 174080000    83G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3   174112768 1044512767 870400000   415G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  1044512768 1925152767 880640000 419.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  1925152768 1953523711  28370944  13.5G Linux swap

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Also, I tried hdparm to check on the disk:
# hdparm -N /dev/sda

/dev/sda:

I know the data (some of it) is there.


How can I tell gdisk that my disk is no zero size?
Can you help me restoring the GPT with some advise?


Your diagnosis information suggest the disk was MBR not GPT

"the GPT is corrupted" - You seem to conflate the "GPT" (a partition table), partitions, and filesystems, and perhaps don't even know the difference between them. "I have a disk that was forcefully closed ..." - How did you "close" a "disk"?

To be clear it’s a problem, a major problem, if a tool detects that the disk is/was both GPT and MBR.

@Ramhound - FYI the GPT scheme uses a fake MBR for an attempt at backwards compatibility. So it may not be a "major problem".

I would be worried that “GPT: not present” and “Found invalid GPT and valid MBR” both suggests the disk was never GPT and only MBR.

"0 sectors" and "sometimes, I can access the disk, then it reports I/O error" suggest a hardware problem. Is the disk connected directly? or via a USB adapter?

I'm pretty sure it was GPT when I created the partitions, @Ramhound.

It is connected directly, @KamilMaciorowski.

Thanks, @JoepvanSteen. I'm on it, following u1686-grawity's advise.

It's so sad to read comments like yours, @sawdust. I'm describing a problem as best as I can. I am not confusing anything. I know the difference between GPT, partitions, and filesystems. Just to be kind to you, because someone else understood the metaphor, I explain it: the laptop was closed during a write operation which brutally shutdown all processes. Isn't one of the values of this site to respond in good faith and with the understanding that not all of us are experts in all technology topics?

From what you described, the GPT is the least of your problems.
This is not just filesystem-level corruption, as you wouldn't be getting I/O errors from the disk itself; and ST1000LM035 is an HDD, and data on an HDD doesn't usually get corrupted out of nowhere, especially if it wasn't even in the process of being written during shutdown – more likely that the HDD was physically damaged and is no longer in a state where you should continue using it.
Either way, if the GPT was the only thing corrupted, you could just keep retrying 'fdisk' or 'gdisk' until it manages to read one of the two copies, then writing it out anew, and it would be "repaired".
But the GPT has only one job, to indicate the list of partitions – really, after your kernel has managed to detect the "sda#" or "nvme#n#p#" partition devices once, it no longer needs the GPT – it already knows where the partitions are. The rest of the mounting process has nothing to do with the GPT at all, so repairing the GPT will do nothing to repair the rest of it.

sometimes, I can access the disk, then it reports I/O error

Probably the only thing to do at this point is to:

get a new disk at least as large as the old one,
connect both to the same system, buy a USB adapter if necessary, verify that both are showing the same "logical sector size",
attempt to copy the whole disk using ddrescue. Not regular dd but specifically ddrescue (and make sure you specify the 3rd "map file" parameter – it helps in case you have to stop and resume the copy). It will keep retrying several times until it gets every sector copied.


When a disk reports its size as zero, this is a case for a professional data recovery lab.
